# Frustating wifi problem on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, airport

I have a MacBook Pro (10.6.7 with latest updates).
Next to me is a TP-LINK TL-WR841 Router.

Sometimes, it says I am connected to the network, but I can't ping anything online. Sometimes, while trying to connect AirPort gives me a "connection time out". Other times, AirPort says it can't find ANY networks.

In all those cases, my friend sitting next to me with his other MacBook pro is online without issues (except every time I annoy him to restart the router).

I tried to restart AirPort, restart the computer, restart the router. My router's channel is on "auto" (currently 1). When connecting via Ethernet everything is fine. I downloaded "iStumbler" which shows one other weak signal on channel 6.

It was working fine yesterday.

Could it be some wireless device interfering with only my laptop? Is my AirPort dead? Are there firmware updates for AirPort?

Comment: I *may* have found my answer. I read online that channels 1-4 are somewhat restricted in Israel (where I am right now). I switched it to channel 11 and it seems to work so far ...

Comment: That's your answer. I've found that generally channels 5-11 will work in most of the world for 802.11b/g/n (just checked Wikipedia and it indicates the same: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels )

Comment: Is there anything we can do to get a good answer for you here or should we close this as something that wasn't reproducible or due to an isolated hardware failure?